# backgroundWorker update progress only at cancellation

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to show on form a 'dinamic label' that just write 'Loading' while another thread it's working.
The label should change in this mode:

L, Lo, Loa, Load, Loadi, Loadin, Loading, oading, ading, ding, ing, ng, g

I wrote the code but the 'BackGroundWorker_ProgressChanged event it's called only when the BackGroundWorker.CancellationPending = True.

And at that point, are sent all the updates.

Here the code

```
Public Class Form1

  Dim WithEvents bgw As New BackgroundWorker
  Dim WithEvents I_MyClass As MyNewClass
  Dim lLoading As New Label
  Dim WithEvents T As New Timer

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    I_MyClass = New MyNewClass
    AddHandler I_MyClass.Start, AddressOf StartLoading
    AddHandler I_MyClass.Stop, AddressOf StopLoading

    With lLoading
        .Size = New Size(120, 25)
        .Location = New Point(10, 10)
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(lLoading)

    T.Interval = 1000
    AddHandler T.Tick, AddressOf T_Tick

    T.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub T_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles T.Tick
    T.Stop()
    I_MyClass.StartLoading()
  End Sub

  Public Sub StartLoading()
    If bgw.IsBusy Then Exit Sub
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
  End Sub

  Public Sub StopLoading()
    bgw.CancelAsync()
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
    Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)

    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim loadingString As String = "Loading......."
    Do
        If (worker.CancellationPending = True) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            worker.ReportProgress(i)
            If i = loadingString.Count Then i = 1 Else i += 1
        End If
    Loop
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
    Dim loadingString As String = "Loading......."
    Dim i As Integer = e.ProgressPercentage
    Dim l As Integer = lLoading.Text.Count
    If l < i Then
        lLoading.Text = loadingString.Substring(0, i)
    Else
        lLoading.Text = loadingString.Substring(i, l - i)
    End If
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyNewClass
  Sub New()

  End Sub
  Public Event Start()
  Public Event [Stop]()

  Public Sub StartLoading()
    RaiseEvent Start()
    ' simulate download
    For a = 0 To 10
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next a
    RaiseEvent Stop()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Don't understand why the 'BackGroundWorker_ProgressChanged event it's not called reporting partial progress, but it's called several times only when the BackGroundWorker.CancellationPending = True.

P.S. Also c# help are welcome.

Comment: @ mjwills: indeterminate, it depends on the downloading time, should be a 'dinamic label' that 'rotate' the word 'Loading' until the download it's done

Comment: Add a breakpoint to `worker.ReportProgress(i)`. Debug through the code. How many times was `worker.ReportProgress(i)` called?

Comment: @ mjwills: in my app it's called about 18 times, and the ReportProgress it's not called, then when the download it's made, the backGroundWorker.CancelAsync it's called and the ReportProgress it's called subsequentially 18 times. (N.B. Seems as the ReportProgress are collected and sent only when the BackGroundWorker has been cancelled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't understand why the 'BackGroundWorker_ProgressChanged event it's not called reporting partial progress

Because you have a timer that starts the very blocking, very not-async StartLoading method.

It appears you call this code from the main thread:

```
    For a = 0 to 10
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next a
```

so your app will be completely deaf and dumb for 11 seconds. No time for screen updates or progress events, we are busy with sleeping.

Comment: Yeah... I had noticed.

Comment: @bommelding: Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bommelding, i noticed that i forgot to start the download in a separate thread, so as Bommelding let me notice, the instruction 'threading.thread.sleep() was stopping the Label update
Here the code corrected.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

  Dim WithEvents bgw As New BackgroundWorker
  Dim WithEvents I_MyClass As MyNewClass
  Dim lLoading As New Label
  Dim WithEvents T As New Timer

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    I_MyClass = New MyNewClass
    AddHandler I_MyClass.Start, AddressOf StartLoading
    AddHandler I_MyClass.Stop, AddressOf StopLoading

    With lLoading
        .Size = New Size(120, 25)
        .Location = New Point(10, 10)
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Tag = "Loading"
        For a = 0 To CStr(.Tag).Count - 1
            .Text += " "
        Next
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(lLoading)

    T.Interval = 1000
    AddHandler T.Tick, AddressOf T_Tick

    T.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub T_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles T.Tick
    T.Stop()
    I_MyClass.StartLoading()
  End Sub

  Public Sub StartLoading()
    If bgw.IsBusy Then Exit Sub
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync(CStr(lLoading.Tag).Count - 1)
  End Sub

  Public Sub StopLoading()
    bgw.CancelAsync()
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
    Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    Dim limit As Integer = CInt(e.Argument)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do
        If (worker.CancellationPending = True) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            worker.ReportProgress(i)
            If i = limit Then i = 0 Else i += 1
        End If
    Loop
    i = Nothing
    limit = Nothing
    worker = Nothing
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
    Dim loadingString As String = CStr(lLoading.Tag)

    Dim i As Integer = e.ProgressPercentage
    'Dim l As Integer = lLoading.Text.Count
    If lLoading.Text(i) <> loadingString(i) Then
        Mid(lLoading.Text, i + 1, 1) = loadingString(i)
    Else
        Mid(lLoading.Text, i + 1, 1) = " "
    End If
    i = Nothing
    loadingString = Nothing
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
    For a = 0 To CStr(lLoading.Tag).Count - 1
        lLoading.Text += " "
    Next
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyNewClass
  Sub New()
    bgwDoSameWork.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bgwDoSameWork.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
  End Sub
  Public Event Start()
  Public Event [Stop]()
  Private WithEvents bgwDoSameWork As New BackgroundWorker


  Public Sub StartLoading()
    ' simulate download
    If bgwDoSameWork.IsBusy = False Then
        RaiseEvent Start()
        bgwDoSameWork.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub bgwDoSameWork_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwDoSameWork.DoWork
    For a = 0 To 10
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next a
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgwDoSameWork_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwDoSameWork.RunWorkerCompleted
    RaiseEvent Stop()
  End Sub
End Class
```